# accessing Apache camel header in spring expression language

Tags: spring, apache-camel, spring-el

I want to access camel exchange header value while parsing spring expression.

## 1.

Is it possible ? I am looking some thing like below.

```
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("request.headers['myHeader'].concat('!')");
    String message = (String) exp.getValue();
    System.out.println(message);
```

or can we use @Header and access the same ?
Is there any other way than adding the value to StandardEvaluationContext as variable and then parsing the same ?

Appreciate some quick help on the same.

## 2.

One more question is is there a way i can register all my custom functions at only one place ? I mean i want to avoid registering functions for every call to evaluate the expression. Currently i am doing it below way.

```
public static String evalExpr(String expr,
        Map<String, Object> variables) throws NoSuchMethodException,
        SecurityException {

    StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
    context.registerFunction("concat", CusExprs.class
            .getDeclaredMethod("concat", String[].class));
    context.registerFunction("substr", CustExprs.class
            .getDeclaredMethod("substr", new Class[] { String.class,
                    Integer.class, Integer.class }));
    context.setVariables(variables);
    return parser.parseExpression(expr).getValue(context, String.class);
}
```

Comment: From the docs, "SpEL expressions need to be surrounded by #{ } delimiters since expression templating is enabled" - try that around your `parseExpression` argument.

Comment: correct. But If # is used it looks for a bean named request in spring context. Actually "request.headers['myHeader']" works in camel expression. I want to to know how i can refer to it with out explicitly adding it to StandardEvaluationContext